# security certificate SSL weblogic

Tags: ssl, weblogic

I am getting the following error on weblogic.

Can someone tell how to uninstall demo CA Certificate

```
 The system is vulnerable to security attacks, since it trusts certificates signed by the demo trusted CA.>
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem 
3, 2017 10:56:59 AM CET> <Alert> <Security> <BEA-090152> <Demo trusted CA certificate is being used in production mode: [
```

Comment: create and install a new keystore with your own certificate inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a warning message because weblogic is using it's own demo certificate. If you want to remove this alert then you need to install self signed/CA signed certificates. For that you need to follow below steps:

1. Create keystore and generate key
2. Generate CSR
3. Generate self signed/CA signed certificates
4. Import certificates into your keystore 
   (use keytool command of java to execute steps 1,2 and 4)
5. Changes in WebLogic Admin console:
   Login to admin console --> Open server on which you want to implement SSL --> configuration --> click on SSL Listen port enabled

   Configuration --> Keystore tab --> Change keystore to "Custom Identity and Custom Trust" --> Fill your keystore location to Identity and Custom trust text boxes

   Click on SSL tab and enter your private key alias and passphrase from keystore